# Looking for the name of this property of the cross product, generalised to Lie algebras

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

It is well known that for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $O \in SO(3)$ we have $O(x \times y) = Ox \times Oy$.

When does it hold, for $X, Y \in \mathfrak{g}$ and $g \in G$ with $\mathfrak{g} = \operatorname{Lie}(G)$ that $[gX, gY] = g[X,Y]$. Where $gX$ denotes the action of a Lie group on its algebra by the differential of the left (or right) translation action on itself.

I tried googling something like "$G$ equivariance of $\operatorname{ad}$" but nothing came up. I definitely feel like this should be true for more than just $SO(3)$. At least matrix Lie groups perhaps.

Comment: It's very very close, how can I get rid of the factors of $g^{-1}$ on the right that $\operatorname{Ad}$ introduces so I can say it generalises the $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ example?

Comment: Ok I read the answer, so would it be correct to interpret $gX$ as a left invariant vector field on $TG$ so I can turn the Lie algebra bracket to a vector field Lie bracket, use this property of diffeomorphism pushforwards, $X, Y$ are still (trivially constant?) left invariant vector fields on $TG$ so I can map them back to Lie algebra brackets, now with the diffeomorphism pushing them forward?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I would not agree that $gX$ is the analogue of $Ox$ in this example - instead $\operatorname{Ad}_gX$ is, using the correspondence
$$
\mathbf{x} = (x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \longleftrightarrow \hat{\mathbf{x}} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -x_3 & x_2 \\ x_3 & 0 & -x_1 \\ -x_2 & x_1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\in\mathfrak{so}(3).
$$
Then it is not too difficult to check that 
$
[\hat{\mathbf{x}}, \hat{\mathbf{y}}] = \widehat{\mathbf{x\times y}}
$
and 
$
\operatorname{Ad}_O\hat{\mathbf{x}} = \widehat{O\mathbf{x}}.
$ Applying $\operatorname{Ad}_O$ to the commutation relations gives the property.

Comment: @user17945 I see, so it is in fact a direct application of what is shown in the other question. Do you know if my reasoning that $[gX,gY] = g[X,Y]$ holds due to $(L_g)_*$ being a diffeomorphism remains true, even if it isn't the correct analogy for what happens in $SO(3)$? I am interested in showing this identity holds.

Comment: If $L_g:G\to G$ denotes left multiplication by $g\in G$, and $X,Y$ are vector fields on $G$ (not necessarily left-invariant), then it is certainly true that $(L_g)_*[X,Y] = [(L_g)_*X, (L_g)_*Y]$, where $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is the Jacobi-Lie bracket on $G$. But it wouldn't be correct to interpret $[(L_g)_*X,(L_g)_*Y]$ as $gXgY - gYgX$ where juxtaposition denotes matrix multiplication.

Comment: Right, not the matrix commutator, but if $X,Y$ were left invariant, then their pushforward would remain so, and then the Jacobi-Lie bracket can be seen as a Lie bracket on $\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis But if they are left invariant then left translation doesn't change them and the statement is vacuously true. Instead you should think of the Lie group acting on the Lie algebra via the adjoint action as that gives a non-trivial representation. Then we have the corresponding (but now useful) result: $$\mathrm{Ad}_g([X,Y])=[\mathrm{Ad}_g(X),\mathrm{Ad}_g(Y)]$$

Comment: Right, I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Callum I've been thinking about this question again and considering asking another. $[X,Y]$ is a Lie algebra element, suppose it can be identified with right invariant vector field on $TG$ and so $\operatorname{Ad}_g([X,Y]) = L_{{g}*} R_{{g^{-1}}*} [X,Y] = L_{{g}*} [X,Y] $ and likewise for $[\operatorname{Ad}_gX, \operatorname{Ad}_gY]$. Is this what is going on with $SO(3)$? or is it purely a coincidence of algebra that $SO(3)$ has left translation acting like a Lie algebra homomorphism.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis I feel like this is bending over backwards to avoid thinking of it as the adjoint action. Yes by the identification of $\mathfrak{g}$ as right/left invariant vector fields the adjoint action could be viewed as left/right translation by $g$/$g^{-1}$ but this doesn't feel like a more useful perspective than viewing $\mathfrak{g}$ as the tangent space at the identity and translating on both sides. Either way the thing we care about ultimately is the action itself and I don't think this helps you understand how it acts.

Comment: The reason I ask is because in the problems I've been working on I find myself constantly running into antisymmetric commutator type terms of Lie algebra elements being left or right translated, not the Adjoint action and I'm very interested in rewriting these as a whole Lie algebra bracket which would have a lot of useful geometric meaning for me, so yes I'm sort of fishing for something pretty by trying to look for these formulas.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis can you give an example as, to me, left translating a Lie algebra element is either not changing anything or produces something that is no longer a Lie algebra element depending on your perspective?

Comment: @Callum For example, the Euler Poincare equation on a Lie Algebra is written $\dot{\mu} = \operatorname{ad}^*_{u}\mu$ with velocity $g^{-1}\dot{g} = u \in \mathfrak{g}$, this is thought of as pulling back the velocity $\dot{g}(t)$ on the tangent space $T_{g(t)}G$ back to the algebra, equivalent to $\dot{g} = gu$. I have a situation where there is a new term $\dot{g} = gu + [gX,gY]$ as a v.f. bracket and I want to say that this is equal to $gu + g[X,Y]$ so that the velocity of the modified EP eqn has been shifted by the constant Lie algebra element $[X,Y]$ via $g^{-1}\dot{g} = u + [X,Y]$.

Comment: Okay so the important thing to note now is that $g$ is no longer a constant so that is different to your above question. But we are still just pushing $X,Y$ along their associated left invariant vector fields so it is true that $L_g [X,Y] = [L_gX, L_gY]$. I think writing this as $g[X,Y]=[gX,gY]$ is confusing though so I would suggest using different notation for left translation and the logarithmic derivative or making it clear whenever you use it exactly what you mean.

Comment: I'm struggling to see what the difference was between this situation and when you said ${L_g}_*[X,Y] = [{L_g}_*X, {L_g}_*Y] $ is correct but vacuously true. Thank you for.your help so far.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis The difference is subtle and fairly superficial. Viewing $X$ as a left-invariant vector field it is obvious that $L_gX = X$ (I will drop the $*$ throughout for ease). Viewing $X$ as an element of $T_eG$ we may have to think about this for a second longer but we could convert to the other picture where it is obvious. Then you are creating a new situation when you say $g$ is a curve in $G$. Now we are definitely starting with the $X \in T_eG$ picture and $L_g$ is no longer a fixed map.

Comment: Of course for each individual $g$, $L_{g(t)}X$ is exactly the value of the left-invariant vector field associated to $X$ at $g(t)$ (and hence this all works out neatly) but we are now viewing $L_{g(t)}X$ (probably) as an element of $T_{g(t)}G$. So it is true but I think it takes a second more to see it.

Comment: Ah! I see! So it isn't trivial because $g(t)$ changes. But it's true because of properties of pushforward. Thank you very much for helping it all click.